# How to render the wordcloud in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

While going through [topic modelling with `lda`](http://bridge.library.wisc.edu/hw1a-Rcoding-Jockers.html), I have to render the `wordcloud` output in the main panel of shiny,

The following lines define the worldcloud I have to render:

```
i <- 1
cloud.data <- sort(result$topics[i, ], decreasing = TRUE)[1:50]
wordcloud(names(cloud.data), freq = cloud.data, scale = c(4, 0.1), min.freq = 1, 
    rot.per = 0, random.order = FALSE)
```

I tried in `renderPlot` but it is giving me following error..

```
shiny::runApp('~/RProject/dynamic_UI')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3358
Error in if (grepl(tails, words[i])) ht <- ht + ht * 0.2 : 
  argument is of length zero
Warning in run(timeoutMs) : "min.freq" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in run(timeoutMs) : "min.freq" is not a graphical parameter
```

Then I corrected some parameters (for example, `min.freqs` for `min.freq`), getting now the following error:

```
shiny::runApp('~/RProject/dynamic_UI')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3358
Read 8265 items
Error in if (grepl(tails, words[i])) ht <- ht + ht * 0.2 : 
  argument is of length zero
Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

How could I render the `wordcloud` output in the main panel?

Comment: Does the wordcloud render correctly outside of Shiny?

Comment: yes @kristang it works fine outside of shiny.

Comment: sorry @kristang after correction some parameter like min.freqs should be min.freq I got error I have updated.

Comment: Not familiar with `wordcloud` but I can see that `grepl` is throwing the error, so most likely there is something in the input text-string that is causing the issue.

Comment: thanxh @kristang I had the output issue .. with my wordcloud function,, well as I solved this problem should I delete my question?

Comment: No, I think you should add how you found the error, and how to solve it so other people with the same issue might find your question if they search :)

Comment: @anupam93, you should consider supplying an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The name of my column did not match: should have been testdoc5$word but I had testdoc5$doc. Now it works!